# Angry birds loads, plays, but does not save

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have a TOMCAT with Android 2.3 Angry birds loads, plays, but does not save. When I restart it starts from the beginning and it does this from the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the basics - first try clearing the app's cache:

```
Settings > Applications > Manage Apps > All > Angry Birds > Clear Cache
```

Then if that doesn't work, try re-installing the program.